# how to use the slide show of Skylark in showcase?

Tags: themes, wordpress.com-hosting, slideshow

I created a page and I set the template as *showcase* and then I went to setting->reading
and as a static page I choose my created page.

I'm wondering how I can add slideshows with pictures and sticky posts. I went to documentation [in the link](http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/skylark/#featured-slider) but unfortunately I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome ... this forum is more suited for WordPress selfhosted not WordPress.com sites.

However ... reading the [WordPress.com theme](http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/skylark/#featured-slider) documents it says

> The Showcase page template offers a featured slider for sticky posts. If you’d like a post to appear in the slider, mark it as sticky and assign it a featured image that’s at least 500 pixels wide.

[image]

So please Add a new post and mark it as sticky and add an image. If you're still stuck, try the WordPress.com forums.